# How do I prove that $ t \rightarrow f(G(t),H(t)) $ is continuous?

Tags: continuity

I have to prove that the function $t \rightarrow f(G(t),H(t))$ is continuous in $[0,1]$.

I know the following: 
Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function. Let $ G : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $H : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be contonius functions such that $(G(t),H(t)) \in D \ \forall \ t \in [0,1]$.

Do I start by using the definition of continuous? $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 : |x-x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$? And if so do I just pick a random $\epsilon > 0$ and find a $\delta >0$?

I am really not sure how to start. Can you help me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the sequential definition of continuity?

Comment: Yes. Can I use that and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $t_n \to t$ then $G(t_n) \to G(t)$ and $H(t_n) \to H(t)$. Hence $(G(t_n),H(t_n)) \to (G(t),H(t))$ which implies   $f(G(t_n),H(t_n)) \to f(G(t),H(t))$.

Comment: So we use the fact that the function f is contonius to prove that $f(G(t),H(t))$ is contonius in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Yes. Proof using $\epsilon -\delta$  involves uniform continuity of $f$ restricted to compact subsets. It is much more complicated the proof using sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Kavi.